# How to match a string inside double square brackets?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have multiple files with data similar to the following example:

```
 [[Public IP Addresses ]]  
// Here, IP addresses will   
 IPv6 display format.  
[LINK_7]  
linkNum=7.
```

Here i have to extract "Public IP Addresses".i.e whatever is inside double square brackets. i.e I want a sed/awk/grep etc script to extract whatever is inside the double square brackets.
 I have tried lot of options in vain. Some help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly looking for

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])' file.txt
```

Where `man grep`:

```
-P, --perl-regexp
       Interpret the pattern as a  Perl-compatible  regular  expression
       (PCRE).   This  is  highly  experimental and grep -P may warn of
       unimplemented features.
-o, --only-matching
       Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
       with each such part on a separate output line.
```

The [working example at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yiTJjs/1) does also provide a break-down of the regular expression.

Example:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])' <<EOF
[[Public IP Addresses ]]
// Here, IP addresses will
IPv6 display format.
[LINK_7]
linkNum=7.
EOF
Public IP Addresses
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a pure bash solution, assuming an input file of `gash.txt`:

```
while read -r
do
    if [[ $REPLY == *'[['*']]'* ]]
    then
        extract=${REPLY/*'[['/}
        extract=${extract/']]'*/}
        echo "$extract"
    fi
done < gash.txt
```

Comment: What about this: `[[ $REPLY =~ '[['(.*)']]' ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` ? :)